# Netbeans plugin ClassNotFoundException for existing class

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, classloader

I'm working on Netbeans plugin, based on http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html tutorial. When I start and debug my plugin, an exception is raised:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.swing.text.BadLocationException     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) Caused:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/text/BadLocationException
>     at
>   pl.artpal.hinttest.CodeCompletionProvider$1.query(CodeCompletionProvider.java:35)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.spi.editor.completion.support.AsyncCompletionTask.run(AsyncCompletionTask.java:223)
>     at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1452)
>   [catch] at
>   org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2032)

BadLocationException class is part of javax.swing.text package, it should be loaded from rt.jar

Of course, my java file has

```
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
```

According to debug-time netbeans command line,

```
javax.swing.text.BadLocationException.class
```

doesn't exist, but when I try:

```
Class.forName("javax.swing.text.BadLocationException").getConstructors()[0].newInstance(new Object[] { "a", 1}).toString()
```

It works. What's going on?

Netbeans v7.2.1, JDK 1.7.0_13, JRE7, Win7x64, I have also Eclipse on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I see ClassNotFoundException when system resources (memory) are low. When it cleans up exceptions are gone. Making infinite cycle of new Class() may lead you there.

If this is not the case, see here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html